# An object '' of type Dashboard was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory

Tags: metadata, dashboard, package.xml, deployment-error, mdapideploy

When I am trying to deploy a dashboard with its dashboard folder, I am receiving an error through package.xml. Below is the error:

> Error SalesRepDashboardsTableauxdebord
> An object 'SalesRepDashboardsTableauxdebord' of type Dashboard was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory
> Error SalesRepDashboardsTableauxdebord/OpportunityTrending
> An object 'SalesRepDashboardsTableauxdebord/OpportunityTrending' of type Dashboard was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory

Dashboard Folder name : SalesRepDashboardsTableauxdebord

Dashboard Name : OpportunityTrending

package.xml like this:

```xml
<types>
    <members>SalesRepDashboardsTableauxdebord</members>
    <members>SalesRepDashboardsTableauxdebord/OpportunityTrending</members>
    <name>Dashboard</name>
</types>
```

Please guide me what is the reason for this error coming?

Comment: Package.xml is like this which I have used:

<types>
    <members>SalesRepDashboardsTableauxdebord</members>
    <members>SalesRepDashboardsTableauxdebord/OpportunityTrending</members>
    <name>Dashboard</name>
</types>

Answer (score 0):

The dashboard's name usually is just its Title, while you need the dashboard's DeveloperName, which could be a random string like `BLyVDVBHeJKKfpqhKlskcZWtcqzsnK`.
You can find it running this query:

```sql
SELECT DeveloperName
FROM Dashboard
WHERE Title = 'OpportunityTrending'
```

Then replace `OpportunityTrending` with the *DeveloperName* in the package.xml:

```xml
<types>
    <members>SalesRepDashboardsTableauxdebord</members>
    <members>SalesRepDashboardsTableauxdebord/OpportunityTrending_DeveloperName</members>
    <name>Dashboard</name>
</types>
```

Comment: I have already used 'OpportunityTrending' as a developername. It was returned as a developername from the query.

Comment: @Dips browsing your local project, inside the `main/default/dashboards` folder do you have both the `SalesRepDashboardsTableauxdebord` folder (with a `OpportunityTrending.dashboard-meta.xml` file) and the `SalesRepDashboardsTableauxdebord.dashboardFolder-meta.xml` file?